# Cannot dual boot Windows 7 after installing Linux Mint

Tags: multi-boot, linux-mint

I first installed Windows 7. /dev/sda1 was the system reserved partition for Win 7, and /dev/sda2 was the C partition. Then I installed Linux Mint. After that, when I started the computer, I could see the "Windows 7 (/dev/sda1)" was listed in the end of boot menu, but I could boot into Windows 7. The only thing I can think of is I might make a mistake in choosing the place the grub was to be installed: I chose /dev/sda1 rather than /dev/sda by default.

Can anyone provide any advice? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall GRUB to /dev/sda.  You install to sda as that is not a partition and GRUB goes into the MBR of that.  Installing to sda1 is a partition, not a hard-drive MBR section, of the drive.

[Here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/245) are instructions to reinstall GRUB in Mint.

Comment: There may also, not saying there will be, corruption on your sda1 partition.  Depends on what GRUB did to it when you installed it there.

Comment: I tried to install grub back to /dev/sda, but without luck... does that mean Linux Mint corrupted the Windows boot information? If so, that's probably the worst case...

Comment: If you have successfully installed GRUB you will get that boot-menu first, regardless, what boots after that depends on the menu entries in your GRUB configuration file.  Do you get a GRUB boot-menu as the first thing that happens when you start your computer?  If you don't then GRUB is not properly installed.

Comment: Depending on how your GRUB is configured as well you may need to hold down the left shift key while booting to see a menu.

Comment: Also, [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/) is how to fix your Windows 7 bootloader.  You can try that and then once you get Windows 7 booting properly again then try to reinstall GRUB hopefully with working boots this time.  And if you want to kill Linux Mint completely after repairing Windows 7's bootloader then use the disk management snap-in once you boot 7 to delete Mint's partition then grow your Windows partition into that now free space.

Comment: After boot from Win 7 install DVD, and fix the bootloader with commands "bootrec /fixmbr" and "bootrec /fixboot", I can now boot into Win 7 again! Now to recover grub in Linux Mint is easy. Problem solved. Thanks Bill!

Comment: Right on, you're welcome! :)